# Style the reset password link

Tags: users

I want to give the reset password link a different class so I can style it. How can I do this in drupal 7? my layout here http://www.lusciousanime.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the link in the right hand login block I'm pretty sure you've already got enough surrounding CSS to target it without adding any more classes, e.g:

```
.block-user #user-login-form a { color: blue; }
```